# I can't close the Inspector window in unity3d. The Close Tab option is disabled. What can i do?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I played around with the windows Game, Scene, Hierarchy...Then the Inspector is all over the editor and i don't have the Close Tab option. I tried to close and load the unity editor again but it didn't help. Once i'm loading the project or the scene file i'm getting: I also tried to create a new complete project but still what i see is this:

[image: Unity Editor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `Layout` dropdown at the top right of the window (right below the X close button)? Click it, select "Defaut", there you go.